# Is it safe to use "uninsulated crimp" crimpers on insulated crimps?

Tags: connector, crimp

Besides needing a bigger size, will it work to use crimpers meant for uninsulated crimps on insulated? Will it crack the insulation or cause other significant problems?

[image: insulated crimp] [image: uninsulated crimp]

Comment: Crescent crimpers are okay (but not great), but pinch crimpers will be pain.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 stage crimps on wire and insulation are compressed by precise ratios of diameter against materials with different stiffness.  The difference between an under-compressed crimp that fails a 5 lb pull test and an over-crompressed crimp that displaces the material beyond some elastic limit that results in less spring tension is a fine line of skill.  The tool makes it easier to meet the force and compresssion size ratios to maximize the strength and make an gas-tight oxide-free bond.

But if you are desperate, go for it, but it has to survive a 5 lb pull test to be reliable on  a consistent basis, but you may get lucky .

Comment: You sure about the 5 lb pull test?  I seem to recall the standard for a good crimp was 75% of wire breaking strength.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the Pull-Out test which for AWG 20 is 13 lbs, AWG16 is 20 lbs.   A minimum of 5 slow pull force measurements
should be done to confirm each set-up. A minimum of 25 readings
should be taken for capability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done it but it's not the best.  A SuperChamp is kind of the gold standard for simple hand-held crimpers but there cheaper ones out there that will crimp both.  Below is one from Ideal.[image]